# Usage of Broadcast Variables when using only Spark-SQL API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When using the Spark-RDD API, we can use broadcast-variables to optimize the way spark distributes immutable state.

#### 1) How do broadcast-variables work internally?

My assumption is:
With every closure that is used to perform an operation on the dataset, all it's referenced variables have to be serialized, transferred over the network and restored along with the task so that the closure can be executed.

When registering a broadcast-variable like this:

```scala
val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast("hello world")
```

the returned object (`Broadcast[String]`) doesn't keep a reference to the actual object ("hello world") but only some ID.
When a broadcast-variable-handle is being referenced from within a closure like said above, it will be serialized just the way every other variable is - just that a broadcast-variable-handle itself doesn't contain the actual object.

When the closure is later being executed on the target nodes, the actual object ("hello world") has been already transferred to each node. When the closure hits the point where `broadcastVar.value` is called, the broadcast-variable-handle internally retrieves the actual object using the ID.

Is this assumption correct?

#### 2) Is there a way to take advantage of this mechanism in Spark-SQL?

Let's say I have a set of values that is allowed.

When using the RDD-API I would create a broadcast-variable for my allowedValues:

```scala
val broadcastAllowedValues = sc.broadcast(allowedValues) // Broadcast[Set[String]]

rdd.filter(row => broadcastAllowedValues.value.contains(row("mycol")))
```

Naturally, when using the Spark-SQL-API I would use the `Column.isin` / `Column.isInCollection` method for that:

```scala
dataframe.where(col("mycol").isInCollection(allowedValues))
```

but it seems like I can't get the advantage of a broadcast-variable this way.

Also, if I would change this piece of code to the following:

```scala
val broadcastAllowedValues = sc.broadcast(allowedValues) // Broadcast[Set[String]]

dataframe.where(col("mycol").isInCollection(allowedValues.value))
```

this part:

```scala
col("mycol").isInCollection(allowedValues.value)
// and more important this part:
allowedValues.value
```

will already be evaluated on the driver, resulting in a new `Column`-Object. So the broadcast-variable looses it's advantage here. It even would have some overhead compared to the first example ...

Is there a way to take advantage of Broadcast-Variables using the Spark-SQL-API or do I have to explicitly use the RDD-API at these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do broadcast-variables work internally?

The broadcasted data is serialized and physically moved to all executors. According to the documentation on [Broadcast Variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), it says

"Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks."

> Is there a way to take advantage of this mechanism in Spark-SQL?

Yes, there is a way to take advantages. Spark applied by default a *Broadcast Hash Join* when joining a big and small Dataframe.

According to the book "Learning Spark - 2nd edition", it says:

"By default Spark will use a broadcast join if the smaller data set is less then 10MB. This configuration is set in `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`; you can decrease or increase the size depending on how much memory you have on each executor and in the driver."

In your case you need to list all unique *allowedValues* into a simple DataFrame (dataframe called `allowedeValuesDF`) with only one column (column called `allowValues`) and apply a join to filter your `dataframe`.

Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val result = dataframe.join(broadcast(allowedValuesDF), "mycol === allowedValues")
```

Actually, you could leave out the `broadcast` as Spark will do a broadcast join by default.

Edit:

In later versions of Spark you could also use *join hints* in the SQL syntax to tell the execution engine which strategies to use. Details are provided in the [SQL Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html#join-hints) and an example is provided below:

```sql
-- Join Hints for broadcast join 
SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(t1) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.key = t2.key;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested the time difference between 3 variants of my filter based on your answer (see: https://pastebin.com/rwgkTDPC )
Actually, the third method (`runWithBroadcastVariable`) is the fastest of all on my setup. The join is just a bit slower. But what I can't understand is, why is the first one ( `runWithInCollection` actually about 10 times slower than both other variants. In theory, shouldn't it be almost equivalent to `runWithBroadcastVariable` ?

I know this is not a benchmark configuration, but the time diff is significant

Comment: You are right, this does not look like a proper benchmark. I am sure there are cases when simply broadcasting is faster as a *hashed* join, especiaööy when it come to simpöe number rangers where a hash will not have any improvement but just add some costs. I am also not familiar with the `spark.run` measurement and what it actually takes into account. Maybe looking at the `explain` graph of the dataframe sheds some more light.

Comment: This `explain` graph will probaböy show that `runWithInCollection` requires a lot of data shuffling accross the partitions which is quite costly.

Comment: Actually, `runWithInCollection` doesnt require any shuffling at all. But it would normally create an dynamic implementation of some class, which doesn't work if the collection is too large (10000 Ints seem already be too large to be compiled). When using only 500 allowedValues for example, the `runWithInCollection` is actually the fastest of all 3
See:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33383